# Apache Proxy Balancer fails to recognize a dead server

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I have two VMs, with identical configuration, but one of them fails to recognize secondary `BalancerMember` as not available.

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)
Server built:   May 28 2018 16:19:32

<Proxy balancer://SuperDuperBalancer>
  ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness failontimeout=on
  BalancerMember http://serverOne:9300 route=app01 timeout=1
  BalancerMember http://BiteMeYouShouldBeDead:9300 route=app03 status=-SE timeout=1 retry=2 connectiontimeout=1 ping=1
</Proxy>
```

I still get `Status - Init OK` instead of the expected `Status - Init Err`. 
Has anyone seen this behavior?

Comment: So one VM sees the second balancermember as dead but the other vm does not?

Comment: Exactly, @mzhaase